# Database Design for Attendance Management

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am creating a attendance management website for college and so far I have this:

```
AttendanceId Pk,
RollNo,
Date,
Lecture1,
Lecture2,
Lecture3,
Lecture4,
Lecture5...till lecture10
```

Attendance in every lecture is to be recorded.

I know this is not a very good design since there are so many Lecture columns, is there any other way?

How much space would this kind of table consume if suppose attendance of 5000 students is to be recorded everyday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Your table isn't [***normalized***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) this way. Better off, create a new table:

**`AttendanceLectures`**:

- `AttendanceId` a foreign key references Attendances table,
- `LectureId` foreign key references lectures table,
- ...

With a composite key (`ATtendanceId`, `LectureID`).

**`Lectures`**:

- `LectureId`.
- ... other details if any

And your table `Attendances` would be this way:

- `AttendanceId` Pk,
- `RollNo`,
- `AttendanceDate`.

Comment: Your design is great, but the attendance is gonna be uploaded through excel sheets, i am gonna have a really hard time figuring out how to import data into different tables through excelsheet. Importing data into single table is much easier.

Comment: @user2064292 You should orgainze your data that should be exported to match these tables' designs then you can import it normally from the MS SQL SErver management studio directly.

Comment: If the format in excel is like..
date,rollno,lect1,lect2.. date and rollno can be imported directly into Attendances table, but how do i insert AttendanceId and LectureId and status in AttendanceLectures table?

Comment: in case i use just a single table, how disastrous can it be?(estimate)

Comment: @user2064292 You can't insert it his way, you have to put these columns values of lect1, lect2 into the form of attendenceid, lectureid and other columns lectureid then import each one into its table columns.